# Generating a short needle pulse

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, frequency, bandwidth

I have an op-amp with a 100 MHz bandwidth. The input of this o-pamp will be a 65 MHz square wave. Can I expect to get something like a needle looking pulse? Because I am only going to have the first harmonic in it?

Comment: With some overdrive without trying linear amplification you can estimate the sharpest possible pulse. Check the Slew Rate spec from the datasheet. It tells how fast (volts per microsecond) the output can change. The shortness must be made with RC highpass filter because the walkthrough time of the input signal forces the pulse to have some length.

Comment: I wouldn't relate this question to an "opamp with a 100 MHz bandwidth", Opamps usually have a very small bw like 10 Hz! The **gain bandwidth product** can be 100 MHz though. But your question assumes that you have an amplifier with a 100 MHz bandwidth so you'd be using that 100 MHz GBP opamp at unity gain. It is much less confusing to mention a 1st order lowpass filter with a (-3 dB) bandwith of 100 MHz.

Comment: To really understand what happens when you pass a 65 MHz square wave through a 100 MHz Lowpass filter, study **fourier analysis**. From that we know that a 65 MHz square wave consists of the sum of odd-order harmonics of 65 MHz so 65 MHz, 195 MHz, 325 MHz etc... All those (except the 65 MHz) will attenuated and that affects the shape of the wave. It will have much less steep transitions making it look like a distorted sine wave. For a "short needle pulse" you will need something completely different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will see something more like a sine wave, or a square wave with rounded edges on the output.

Keep in mind that a "needle" looking pulse (impulse) has very wide bandwidth, and so contains many harmonics above the main frequency.

Comment: Yes you are right, but the period (1/65MHz) of this signal has to stay the same right

Comment: @electrococuk if you model your opamp circuit as still doing something linear, yes. If you model it as being driven into nonlinear behaviour, then, uh, interesting things might happen, but even so, all frequencies generated will tend to be multiples of the fundamental 65 MHz, so yes, the time-periodicity of 1/(65 MHz) will remain.